# Using Openpyxl to update an Excel Template results in Chart no longer displaying data table

Tags: python, excel, charts, datatable, openpyxl

I am updating the data behind a chart using Openpyxl.  When I update the data and save the template as a new file, the excel chart that is created from that data seems to lose its formatting, specifically the data table attached.

I have already tried checking and unchecking "Properties follow chart data point for current / all new workbook(s).

I expect the chart to have the same format as the original excel template.  In this case, the lines on the graph are updated, but the data table underneath the graph disappears.

Below is my openpyxl snippet, though it probably won't be useful.  All I am doing is updating cell values in a loop.

```
    for i in range(0, 12):
        ws_S_EPE['D{}'.format(i+36)] = pr['Energy'][i] / 1000
        ws_S_EPE['E{}'.format(i+36)] = pr['pr'][i]
        ws_S_EPE['F{}'.format(i+36)] = pr_tc['pr_tc'][i]
```

Here are picture of the graph in the template and the file created from the template.

[image: In Template]
[image: Template after Openpyxl]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049140/python-script-erroneously-erases-created-chart-in-xlsx-file

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html

Comment: Which version? Reading might have been added in 2.5     ... https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/523/charts-in-existing-worksheets-lost

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-plotting-charts-in-excel-sheet-using-openpyxl-module-set-3

Comment: hello @Joe  I'm using V2.6.1 so it doesn't look like it is fixed yet.